# What is the formula for calculating Draw down recovery percentage?

Tags: drawdown, recovery

I need the formula to calculate Drawdown recovery percentage showing in this picture.

[image]

If you know please share.
Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the number in the first column is x, then the y value in the second column should be calculated as;

y = x / (1 - x)

Hope this helps

Comment: Proof: After a drop of x followed by a rise of y, the price has been multiplied by $(1-x)(1+y)$.  For the price to be back to the same level as before this product must be equal to 1, therefore we have the equation $(1-x)(1+y)=1$. Solving this for y we get $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$ QED

Comment: You are welcome. Another, equivalent, formula that I find easier to remember (and use with a calculator) is $y=-1+\frac{1}{1-x}$. For example x=0.2: Enter 1, subtract 0.2, take the inverse, subtract 1, you get 0.25. Very easy if your calculator has an inverse key.